# How to make a custom UITableView Index bar using Swift 3/4

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I was wondering how I might make a custom `UITableView` index bar, or at least expand the one that I already have to take up the whole screen.

**Here is the code that I have for the default index:**

```
override func sectionIndexTitles(for tableView: UITableView) -> [String]? {

    //Index titles + customise colours
    setIndexTitleColour(for : tableView, basedOn: weightSearch!)
    return setIndexTitlesForTV(basedOn: title!, searchController)

}
```

**Here is the `setIndexTitlesForTV` code:**

```
func setIndexTitlesForTV(basedOn title: String, _ searchController: UISearchController) -> [String]? {

    //Set titles for index

    //For alphabetical
    if title == "Alphabetical" {

        if searchController.searchBar.text != "" {

            return nil

        } else if searchController.isActive {

            return [""]

        } else {

            let x = ["Q","W","E","R","T","Y","U","I","O","P","A","S","D","F","G","H","J","K","L","Z","X","C","V","B","N","M"]
            return x.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })

        }

        //Else
    } else {

        return nil

    }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: What does setIndexTitlesForTV do?  You need to show much more code.

Comment: No, there is no way to make the indexes down the right side of the table view take up the whole screen.

Comment: https://cocoapods.org/pods/GDIIndexBar